# absolute in relative: adapt position without size

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

If this is a dupe then sorry, but I haven't been able to find it.

I have an absolutely positioned element who's size is currently based on its contents: a requirement in the current case.  However, it is also set directly to the right of its parent, while it needs to be directly below.
To set the absolute element below its parent I set its left and top and make the parent element relatively positioned.  However, when I do this the absolute element adopts the width of its parent element (which is quite small).  I really need the absolute element to define its own width based on its (often times dynamic) content.

Is there an effective way to set the absolute element to be just below its parent while leaving it open to being sized by its content?

**EDIT:**

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/jmheard/esghgjhu/) a jsfiddle link to demonstrate the issue.

Here is the html:

```
<div id='menu'>
    <span class='menuItem'>
        <span class='menuItemTitle'>
            Item 1
        </span>
        <div class='menuItemContent'>
            test1 test1 test1 test1<br/>
            testing testing, one two three<br/>
            Anyone there?
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class='menuItem'>
        <span class='menuItemTitle'>
            Item 2: extra wide
        </span>
        <div class='menuItemContent'>
            test2 test2 test2 test2
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#menu
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
.menuItem
{
    padding: 0 1em;
    //position: relative;
}
.menuItemTitle
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.menuItemContent
{
    background-color: green;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
.menuItem:hover .menuItemContent
{
    display: inherit;
}
```

By default it shows the absolute element with no relative parent.  This allows the element's content to define its width.
If you go down to the ".menuItem" style and uncomment it's position then the absolute element gets squished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An absolutely positioned element is content-sized by default unless you either set both its sides (e.g. "left" and "right"), or explicitly set its width.

So, if your absolutely positioned element is sized relative to the parent, you must be doing one of the above. A good way to test is to use an inspector in, e.g. Firefox or Chrome, to see the computed CSS, and see if it contains one of the above. You can also forcibly prevent those cases by setting `right: auto;` and `width: auto;` on the element.

One small gotcha is that it will still inherit line-breaking rules from its parent. To prevent this, simply set its width to a very large number, like 1000000px. This would prevent line breaking, but also make any relatively sized elements inside of it overly large as well. However, the latter is not a technical problem: A relatively sized element has to be sized relative to *something*, so you either leave it as relative to the parent object, or avoid using relative sizes in the direct children of the absolutely positioned element.

If you need a content-sized border, just put another div inside your absolutely positioned element, make it either absolutely positioned or floating, and give it a border.

If you want to mix elements that are relatively sized with ones that aren't, allow your absolutely positioned element to be sized relative to the parent, but at the same time, wrap individual elements/paragraphs that shouldn't be wrapped with extremely wide divs.

If you want the absolutely positioned element to be sized relative to the parent of the parent, don't make it absolutely positioned at all. Instead, use floats, and make it a direct child of the parent of the parent. For instance, here is a trick I used to make a content-sized sidebar once:

```
<div id="parent" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear:both"><!-- Float parent -->
    <div id="sidebar" style="float: left">
        Dynamic content
    </div>
    <div id="main_content_position" style="float: left"><!-- Extra div to set the position right of the sidebar -->
        <div id="main_content" style="width: 100%"><!-- Inner div with 100% width forces the position div to grow as large as it can, minus the size of the sidebar -->
            My content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="clear_after" style="clear:both"></div><!-- Clear after the floating parent. We don't want it to actually float -->
```

Note that this method is far from perfect. It requires using strict mode (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), and if you're using RTL you're going to need at least one extra div on Firefox, and mess with `overflow:visible` and `overflow:hidden`, otherwise word wrapping will come out broken.

In general, it's a good idea to have your sidebar have a static width, and then use the old float-and-margin trick:

```
<div id="parent" style="width: 100%">
    <div id="sidebar" style="float: left; width: 150px">
        Static content
    </div>
    <div id="main_content" style="margin-left: 150px">
        Dynamic content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** The reason it's "squished" in the JSFiddle is because "content sized" in this instance is based on the largest word. What you, apparently, want, is for it not to introduce line breaks at all.

(Also, you've put a div inside a span which isn't exactly valid, but I'll let that pass)

One solution that partially works is to increase the width of the div and use an inner div, as I've mentioned before:

```
<div class='menuItemContent'>
    <div class='menuItemContentInner'>
        test1 test1 test1 test1<br/>
        testing testing, one two three<br/>
        Anyone there?
    </div>
</div>
```

And add the CSS:

```
.menuItemContent
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 1em;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 10000px;
}
.menuItemContentInner
{
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
```

The flaw with this solution is that it creates a scroll when you hover over the item. Using `overflow:hidden` doesn't fix things, since it also crops things down to the menu's height. Unfortunately, it's not possible to do `overflow:hidden` in just one direction.

After playing around with the fiddler, however, I eventually found this solution:

```
.menuItem
{
    padding: 0 1em;
    float: left;
}
.menuItemContent
{
    background-color: green;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    clear: left;
}
```

And add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` to the end of the menu.

This causes the content to break line and appear below the text, without having to explicitly set its `left` or `top`, so `position:relative` on the item is not necessary. I've tested it in Firefox, Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome. It's actually a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I tried the right: auto; left: auto; as well as the width: 10000px.  These didn't resolve the issue effectively.  I'm editing my question with a jsfiddle link to demonstrate the issue more effectively.

Comment: Sweet!  Thank you very much for checking that.  Impressive testing completeness too.  The "clear" property seems quite useful.  This is my first stackoverflow post, but I'll gain reputation and upvote soon.

Comment: Dear Slug, you said "An absolutely positioned element is content-sized by default unless you either set both its sides (e.g. "left" and "right"), or explicitly set its width.", is there any document support? I am new to CSS and want to learn more...Thanks!

Comment: @Eric The specs define the size of absolutely positioned blocks here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abspos-auto-size
And here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abs-non-replaced-width
But specs can be complex to read, and even in strict mode, not all are guaranteed. In practice, there's no real substitute to simply trying things out in several browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this with a drop down hover sub menu on a website. The solution I found was setting the child 'absolute' element's white-space to 'nowrap'.
In my specific case:

```
&.menu-item-has-children {
    position: relative;
    .sub-menu {
        position: absolute;
        li a {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    }
}
```

This allowed the absolute element to position according to its parent but still allow its width to be based on its content which was wider than its parent.